# I have to refresh the page everytime I change and upload a new profile picture how do I make so I don't have to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, react-hooks

Below is the my profile page code I thinking I should use a callback along with another useEffect function but I'm not sure please help. You ignore all the code involving deleting, saving, and handling ingredients I just working on the profile card for right now plus those already work. I really just don't want the user to have to refresh the page every time they upload a new image to see it. Unless you all have other fun way of getting around this or suggest i just make another modal telling the user to refresh the page or any other creative way to make this feature seem less bad and unprofessional. I'm a beginner and would really appreciate some help with this!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";
import "./Profile.css";

const Profile = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const [savedIngredients, setSavedIngredients] = useState([]);
  const [ingredientName, setIngredientName] = useState("");
  const [ingredientQuantity, setIngredientQuantity] = useState("");
  const [ingredientOptions, setIngredientOptions] = useState([]);

  const [showIngredientModal, setShowIngredientModal] = useState(false); // State to control the ingredient modal
  const [selectedIngredient, setSelectedIngredient] = useState(""); // State to store the selected ingredient

  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [showUploadModal, setShowUploadModal] = useState(false);
  const [previewImage, setPreviewImage] = useState(null);
  const [profilePictureURL, setProfilePictureURL] = useState("");

  const [recipeOfTheWeek, setRecipeOfTheWeek] = useState(null);

  const API = "http://localhost:3000"

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    setSelectedFile(file);

    const previewImageURL = file ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : null;
    setPreviewImage(previewImageURL);
  };

  const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  };

  // Get Recipe of the Week
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipeOfTheWeek = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await Axios.get(API+'/recipe/random_recipe');
        setRecipeOfTheWeek(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchRecipeOfTheWeek()
  }, [])

  // Fetch email and username
  function getUserData() {
    const authToken = Cookies.get("userToken");
    Axios.get(
      API+"/users/profile",
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
        },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Profile response:", response.data);
        setUserData({
          username: response.data.username,
          email: response.data.email,
          profilePicture: response.data.profilePicture,
        });
        setProfilePictureURL(response.data.profilePicture)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, [])

  const { username = "", email = "" } = userData || {};

  // Fridge Section
  const fetchIngredientOptions = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/ingredient_options?query=${ingredientName}`, 
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("userToken")}`,
        },
      });
      setIngredientOptions(response.data.ingredientOptions);
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleIngredientOptionClick = (option) => {
    setSelectedIngredient(option);
    setShowIngredientModal(true);
  };

  // Fetch and display saved ingredients
  const fetchSavedIngredients = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.get(
        API+"/users/saved_ingredients",
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("userToken")}`,
          },
        }
      );
      setSavedIngredients(response.data.savedIngredients);
      // setIngredientName("");
      // setIngredientQuantity("");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSavedIngredients();
  }, []);

  const handleAddIngredient = async () => {
    try {

      const ingredientName = selectedIngredient;

      const response = await Axios.post(
        API+"/users/profile_ingredient_list",
        {
          name: ingredientName,
          quantity: ingredientQuantity,
        },
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("userToken")}`,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data); 
      // Only fetch ingredients after a successful save
      fetchSavedIngredients();    
      // empty input fields
      setIngredientName("");
      setIngredientQuantity("");
      // closing Modal
      console.log("Adding ingredient:", selectedIngredient);
      setShowIngredientModal(false);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteIngredient = async (ingredientName) => {
    try {
      const response = await Axios.delete(
        API+"/users/delete_ingredient",
        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("userToken")}`,
          },
          data: {
            name: ingredientName,
          },
        }
      );
      setSavedIngredients(response.data.savedIngredients);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  // Photo Section

  // post profile picture
  const handleProfilePictureUpload = async () => {
    try {
      if (selectedFile) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("profilePicture", selectedFile);

        const response = await Axios.post(
          API + "/users/upload_profile_picture",
          formData,
          {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("userToken")}`,
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        );

        if (response){
          getUserData();
          setShowUploadModal(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };



  return (
    <div className="Profile-Page">
      <Header />
      <div className="top-section">
        <div className="Left-Panel">
          <div className="Profile-Card">
            <div className="Profile-Picture">
              <div className="picture-icon" onClick={() => setShowUploadModal(true)}> 
                <img 
                  className="pic-icon" 
                  src="./images/profile/photo_icon.png" 
                  alt="Add Photo"
                />
              </div>
              {profilePictureURL ? ( 
                <img 
                className="profile-pic"
                src={`http://localhost:3000/uploads/${profilePictureURL}`} 
                alt="Profile"
              />
              ) : (
                <img 
                  className="default" 
                  src="./images/profile/profile_pic.jpg"
                  alt="Default Profile"
                />
              )}
            </div>
            
            <div className="card-content">
              <h1>Profile</h1>
              <p>Username: {username}</p>
              <p>Email: {email}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          {showUploadModal && (
          <div className="upload-modal">
            <div className="upload-modal-content">
              <input
                type="file"
                accept="image/jpg, image/png, image/jpeg"
                id="file"
                onChange={handleFileChange}
                style={{ display: 'none' }}
              />
              <label htmlFor="file" className="file-input-button">
                Change Profile Picture
              </label>
              {previewImage && (
                <img
                  className="preview-image"
                  src={previewImage}
                  alt="Preview"
                />
              )}
              <button type="button" className="pic-upload" onClick={handleProfilePictureUpload}>
                Upload Picture
              </button>
              <button type="button" className="pic-cancel" onClick={() => setShowUploadModal(false)}>
                Cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          )}
          <div className="Meal-of-Week">
            <h1> Meal of the Week </h1>
            { recipeOfTheWeek && (
              <>
                {/* Link */}
                <img className="r-arrow" src="./images/profile/r_arrow.png" alt="RecipeOftheWeek"/>
                {/* Display the picture */}
                <img className="recipe-img" src={`http://localhost:3000/recipe_images/${recipeOfTheWeek.image}`} alt="Recipe" />
                {/* <p>{recipeOfTheWeek.title}</p> */}
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="Right-Panel">
          {/* <h2>FAVORITE RECIPES</h2> */}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="middle-section">
        <div className="L-Panel">
        <form className="add-items">
          <h3>Ingredients:</h3>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={ingredientName}
            onChange={(e) => setIngredientName(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter Ingredient Name"
          />
          {ingredientOptions.length > 0 && (
            <ul>
              {ingredientOptions.map((option, index) => (
                <li key={index} onClick={() => handleIngredientOptionClick(option)}>
                  {option}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}          
          <input
            type="text"
            value={ingredientQuantity}
            onChange={(e) => setIngredientQuantity(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Quantity"
          />
          <button type="button" onClick={fetchIngredientOptions}>
            Save
          </button>
          {/* Ingredient Modal */}
          {showIngredientModal && (
            <div className="ingredient-modal">
              <div className="modal-content">
                <h2>{selectedIngredient}</h2>
                <button onClick={handleAddIngredient}>Add Ingredient</button>
                <button onClick={() => setShowIngredientModal(false)}>
                  Cancel
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            )
          }
        </form>
        </div>
        <div className="R-Panel">
          <h1>What's in Your Fridge</h1>
          <div className="underline"></div>
          <div className="saved-items">
            <ul className="ingredient-item">
              {savedIngredients &&
                savedIngredients.map((ingredient, index) => (
                  <li key={index}>
                    <h3>{capitalizeFirstLetter(ingredient.name)}</h3>
                    <h3>Quantity: {ingredient.quantity}</h3>
                    <button onClick={() => handleDeleteIngredient(ingredient.name)}>
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Here is some of my server code if that helps with understanding what I'm doing.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post("/upload_profile_picture", upload.single("profilePicture"), authenticate, 
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "No profile picture uploaded" });
      }   

      // Save the uploaded file
      const fileName = `${req.userId}_profile_picture`;
      const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../uploads", fileName);
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, req.file.buffer);

      // Update user's profile with the file path
      await Users.update({ profilePicture: fileName }, { where: { id: req.userId } });

      res.json({ message: "Profile Picture uploaded successfully", filePath: fileName });  
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

1. Extract the API method you use to fetch the user details from the `useEffect` into a function

```
function getUserData(){
 const authToken = Cookies.get("userToken");
    Axios.get(
      API+"/users/profile",
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
        },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Profile response:", response.data);
        setUserData({
          username: response.data.username,
          email: response.data.email,
          profilePicture: response.data.profilePicture,
        });
        setProfilePictureURL(response.data.profilePicture)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

}
```

After which you can now call the function inside the `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUserData();
}, [])
```

2. Next, in `handleProfilePictureUpload` call `getUserData` after the profile picture has been successfully uploaded.

```
 const handleProfilePictureUpload = async () => {
    try {
      if (selectedFile) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("profilePicture", selectedFile);

        const response = await Axios.post(
          API + "/users/upload_profile_picture",
          formData,
          {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("userToken")}`,
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        );

        if(response){ // do a check to make sure the response is valid.
           getUserData();
           setShowUploadModal(false);
        }
        
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: Could it be something I'm doing wrong in my server code. I'm not really sure this was a good approach to try though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility you issue is cache please replace

```
src={`http://localhost:3000/uploads/${userData.profilePicture}`}
```

with

```
src={`http://localhost:3000/uploads/${userData.profilePicture}?${new Date().getTime()}`}
```

if it works out then it is cache; you can now create a variable for ${new Date().getTime()} or use number that change in every time the component reload in other to keep a clean code

Answer (score 0):

When using the useEffect hook in React, the dependency array is used to specify which variables or state values the effect depends on. If you provide an empty dependency array ([]), it means the effect has no dependencies and will run once after the initial render.

If you include a variable or state in the dependency array, the effect will run whenever that variable or state changes. This ensures that the effect stays in sync with the specified dependencies.
// Runs on components initial renders

```
// Runs after initial render
   UseEffect(function() {}, [])
// Runs after any state changes
   UseEffect(function() {})
// Will run after the initial render 
// and after the dependency array changes
   UseEffect(function() {}, [setSavedIngredients,setIngredientName, setIngredientQuantity])
```

> Suggestion
> Use the esLint extension on your code editor; esLint will notify you about all of these issues while you are writing the code.
> https://eslint.org/

Comment: your useEffect dependency array is empty so it runs only after the initial render, when you update your states later it won't run again as it doesn't know without the dependency array, use refered states or variables inside the dependency array

Comment: I've tried adding variables inside the dependency array but it didn't work. I even tried deleting the array. I updated the question so I would love to see any more suggestions you have.